# Getting bottom scroll.y when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a nicescroll a plugin that I use to create scrollbars on divs.

```
$('#postscroller').niceScroll();
var nice = $("#postscroller").getNiceScroll()[0];
$('#postscroller').bind("scroll",function()
{
    if(nice.scrollvaluemax==nice.scroll.y)
    {
        alert('bottom');
    }
    alert(nice.scroll.y);
});
```

First I activate the div to be scrolled. 
Then I save the nicescroll instance to the nice variable.

When I test the scroll event to see wether the scroll.y is being fired when I scroll to the bottom I get some numbers but not 134 which is nice.scrollvaluemax in the div I'm testing.

I do get however 134 when I'm at the bottom and I scroll upwards.

Any idea on how can I get 134 when scrolling to the bottom?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you get other numbers because you are **not** at the bottom when you scroll down...

probably related to your current position when the `scroll` is fired.

post more code.

Comment: I added an if condition I have. I think you're right about y not being at the bottom when it scrolls. I was thinking on a timer maybe that checks scroll.y sometime after the scroll stops.

Comment: If I check scroll.y after the scroll stops it does give me 134

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling this at the scroll event

```
var postscrollertimer = (function() {
    var timer; 
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() 
        {
            if(postscroller.scrollvaluemax==postscroller.scroll.y)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
})();
```